# How rails communicate with remote database in a secure way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, data-security

I am using rails for my web application, I have launched my app on heroku. But i am not using heroku database instead i have purchased cpanel and have connected my rails application to a remote database(mysql and phpmyadmin).

I know ssl protects communication between my application and user browsers. **So the question is How my rails app communicate with my remote database. Is it encrypted or not? Is it secure?** **What is rails default behavior?**

I have studied on heroku, they said

> Customer connections to postgres databases require SSL encryption to
>   ensure a high level of security and privacy.  When deploying
>   applications, we encourage customers to take advantage of encrypted
>   database connections. You can read more [here](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security) under data security section.

Comment: On the last paragraph it is saying: `Use of Third-Party Solutions
In developing your application on Heroku you may choose to use third party services for added functionality such as Amazon’s S3, an email service provider, or any of our add-on partners. Be mindful of the data shared with **these providers** and their security practices just as you would be with Heroku.`  But for other providers, you have to check their policies